# logout in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I made an app in react native with react-navigation
I defined the navigation like this:

```
const MainNavigation = (props) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
      console.log(token);
      setToken(token);
    })();
  }, []);
  let screens = (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
  if (token !== null) {
    screens = (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Map" component={Map} />
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeUser" component={HomeUser} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Add" component={Add} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Add2" component={Add2} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {screens}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

in logout component I defined this function for clearing localStorage:

```
pressFn: async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.clear();
        props.navigation.navigate("Home");
      },
```

How I go to home component?
I apreciate any help

Comment: You would add an initialRouteName inside of your Stack.Navigator.. so, when user logout it will clear the token .. you don't have to navigate again to home page if you set it as an initial

Comment: can you show me some code?